# Sonarqube false positive code duplication because of symlink

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I am working in a relatively large codeset with symlinks for some files that point to files somewhere else in the directory tree being analyzed.  Is there a way to tell Sonar to not process a symlinked file as a duplicate?  Ideally I would like the following behavior if I was processing directory /foobar

/foobar/bin/app.py symlinked to /foobar/src/app.py so Sonar would ignore /foobar/bin/app.py

/foobar/bin/app.py symlinked to /foobar2/src/app.py so Sonar would NOT ignore /foobar/bin/app.py because it is linked outside of the /foobar tree.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific "ignore symlinks" behavior to turn on, but you do have the option of setting exclusions for coverage, duplications, issues, or altogether.

At the project level: Settings > General Settings, then choose Exclusions > Duplications and enter regex patterns that describe the files/paths to be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just copied the source tree and did a "find . -type l | xargs rm" before running sonar-runner.